# How to prevent Python Turtle from going through lines it has drawn?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm making a game using Turtle in Python 3.

My main problem is that the turtle can move through the "drawn" lines in the game. It's basically a randomized "flappy-bird" game, different each time you run the program.

Is it possible to prevent the Turtle from going through lines it has drawn?

The program creates both walls and holes the player should be able to get through, like flappy bird where it's a pipe-hole-pipe with different lengths on the pipes.

And if I run `print(hole)` at the end of the program it returns `None`. Why is this?

Here is my program:

```py
import turtle
import random
GameOver=False
import math
import time


board = turtle.Screen()
board.screensize(50.50)
board.bgcolor("black")
board.title("Labyrinten")
Hast_på_ritande_av_bana= 0
TURTLE_SIZE = 20
playerspeed = 50
n=1 #variabeler som gör att den hoppar ett steg åt höger när den gör raderna t.ex. ((930/8)*n)
b=2 #

global player


#SÄTTER UPP SKÄRM
border = turtle.Turtle()
border.speed(Hast_på_ritande_av_bana)

border.hideturtle()
border.color("white")
border.shape("triangle")
border.penup()
border.goto(TURTLE_SIZE/2 - board.window_width()/2, board.window_height()/2 - TURTLE_SIZE/2)
border.pendown()
border.showturtle()

border.rt(90)
border.fd(780)
border.penup()

#ritar banan

for rader in range(4): #creating the maze

    border.lt(90)
    border.fd(930/8)
    border.pendown()
    border.lt(90)
    wall_ett = border.fd(random.randint(50,630))    #lower wall on row 1
    border.penup()
    hole=border.fd(random.randint(30,70))           #hole on row 1
    border.pendown()
    wall_ett_ett = border.goto (TURTLE_SIZE/2 - board.window_width()/2 + (930/8*n), board.window_height()/2 - TURTLE_SIZE/2) #higher wall on row 1
    border.rt(90)
    border.fd(930/8)
    border.rt(90)
    wall_två_ett = border.fd(random.randint(50, 630)) #lower wall on row 2
    border.penup()
    hole2 = border.fd(random.randint(30, 70))         #hole on row 2
    border.pendown()
    wall_två_två = border.goto(TURTLE_SIZE/2 - board.window_width()/2 + (930/8*b), + TURTLE_SIZE/2 - board.window_height()/2 ) # higher wall on row 2
    n = n + 2
    b = b + 2

border.goto(TURTLE_SIZE/2 - board.window_width()/2 , TURTLE_SIZE/2 - board.window_height()/2 )
border.goto(TURTLE_SIZE/2 - board.window_width()/2, board.window_height()/2 - TURTLE_SIZE/2)
border.penup()
border.lt(90)
border.fd(930/8)
border.pendown()
border.goto(-TURTLE_SIZE + board.window_width()/2, board.window_height()/2 - TURTLE_SIZE/2)
border.hideturtle()



player=turtle.Turtle()
player.color("green")
player.shape("turtle")
player.hideturtle()
player.penup()
player.goto(TURTLE_SIZE/2 - board.window_width()/2, board.window_height()/2 - TURTLE_SIZE/2)
player.rt(90)
player.fd(30)
player.lt(90)
player.fd((930/8)/2)
player.rt(90)
player.showturtle()
coordinates = player.pos()







#Skapa spelaren (som går igenom banan)
def spawna_spelare():
    spawn = turtle.Turtle()
    spawn.color("green")
    spawn.shape("turtle")
    spawn.hideturtle()
    spawn.penup()

    spawn.goto(TURTLE_SIZE/2 - board.window_width()/2, board.window_height()/2 - TURTLE_SIZE/2)
    spawn.rt(90)
    spawn.fd(30)
    spawn.lt(90)
    spawn.fd((930/8)*(random.randint(1,8)))
    spawn.rt(90)

    spawn.showturtle()

#Gå med spelaren
def move_left():
    x  = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed

    if x  < -460:
        x = -460
    player.setx(x)

def move_right():

    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    if x > 450:
        x = 450
    player.setx(x)


    if x.distance(wall_ett) >20: #or wall_ett_ett or wall_två_ett or wall_två_två) == 1:  #
        player.shape("triangle")

def move_down():
    y = player.ycor()
    y -= playerspeed
    if y < -375:
        y = -375
    player.sety(y)

def move_up():
    y = player.ycor()
    y += playerspeed

    if y > 380:
        y = 380
    player.sety(y)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(spawna_spelare, "space")
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")
turtle.onkey(move_down, "Down")
turtle.onkey(move_up, "Up")





wall_ett = border.xcor()
wall_två_ett=border.xcor()
print(wall_ett)
print(wall_ett)
print(hole)







board.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome ! I did not manage to run your script, could you produce a minimal reproducible example ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure, or do you mind me posting the entire code? It’s around trice as much as code as i posted above.

Comment: I edited my post and posted the entire game, hope that's okay!

Comment: It works :) I see what you meaned, now, and I believe it'll be easier for you to remember the location of the walls. For example, store the height of the open hole for each wall, and when you detect that the turtle x-position is at a wall position, check that turtle y-position is inside the hole

Comment: Two more remarks. {1} your code is raising a lot of exceptions because `x.distance` does not exists if `x` is a float. You should compute the distance yourself with `abs(x-target)`. {2} hole is None because it is assigned to the result of the function `border.fd`, that does not return a value (which, in python, is the same as returning None).

Comment: Hmm, i don't know how i can detect that "the turtle x-position is at a wall position", i tried setting up boundries in the "move_right()" function just for the first wall but that didnt seem to help:/. Can you explain more what you mean? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I answered a suggestion to do it, trying to keep the same structure as you. I hope you'll get the idea, and finish from there

Comment: Okay, your suggestion differs a bit from mine, and i can admit im probably in the wrong hehe. Thanks for the help, will try to figure it out when i get back home!

Answer (score 0):

So you need to draw the walls in a way you can check afterwards if the move the player requested is crossing any wall (or border).

here is a suggestion:

```py
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
HOLE_HEIGHT = 50
SCREEN_HEIGHT  = 600
NUM_WALLS = 8

board = turtle.Screen()
board.setup(SCREEN_WIDTH+10, SCREEN_HEIGHT+10)
board.screensize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
board.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)

border = turtle.Turtle()
border.speed(10) # draw walls as fast as possible
border.color('white')
border.hideturtle()
# list of the drawn walls, each wall is represented by a tuple:
# (wall_x, wall_hole_lower_y, wall_hole_upper_y)
walls = [] 
for wall_ix in range(NUM_WALLS):
    # compute coordinates of wall and store them
    wall_x = int((1+wall_ix) * SCREEN_WIDTH / (1+NUM_WALLS))
    wall_ybottom = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT - HOLE_HEIGHT)
    wall_ytop = wall_ybottom + HOLE_HEIGHT
    walls.append((wall_x, wall_ytop, wall_ybottom))
    # draw wall
    border.penup()
    border.goto(wall_x, 0)
    border.pendown()
    border.goto(wall_x, wall_ybottom)
    border.penup()
    border.goto(wall_x, wall_ytop)
    border.pendown()
    border.goto(wall_x, SCREEN_HEIGHT)

def move_right():
    old_x  = player.xcor()
    new_x = old_x + playerspeed
    y = player.ycor()

    for wall_x, wall_ytop, wall_ybottom in walls:
        if old_x <= wall_x <= new_x:
            # player is possibly moving across the wall, check that y is valid
            if wall_ybottom < y < wall_ytop:
                # OK ! player moves through the hole
                player.setx(new_x)
            else:
                # invalid, player is crossing a wall line
                # resetting to old position, but you might want to stop the game
                player.setx(old_x)
```